OutgoingResponse from EventReceiver in SP 2019
I'm having a problem with an EventReceiver in SharePoint OnPremise 2019.
This Event Receiver, developed in Visual Studio, launches when a file is added to a document library.
There are 3 events:
ItemAdding
ItemAdded
ItemUpdated
In the ItemAdding event, we check that the file uploaded is a ZIP file, that the person has the right to uninstall a file, and so on.
And we return a custom error message via ctx.OutgoingResponse.
// verification si le fichier est bien en .ZIP
                    if (extension.ToUpper() != "ZIP")
                    {
                        var errorMsg = Tools.ResourceHelper.GetResource("ERRMSG_FILE_EXTENSION", ResourceFile);
                        properties.ErrorMessage = errorMsg;
                        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;

                        throw new Exception(errorMsg);
                    }

catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMessage = "Event: ItemAdding " + ex.Message;
                    properties.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                    properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
                    SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0, new SPDiagnosticsCategory("FranceAssureurs.DepotZIP", TraceSeverity.Unexpected, EventSeverity.Error), TraceSeverity.Unexpected, errorMessage, ex.StackTrace);

                    // Manage http error return
                    WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
                    ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription =  ex.Message;
                }

We add a file to this library from a Front application in React, using the SharePoint APIs:
const url = `${this.props.library}/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='${file.name}', overwrite=true)`;

      this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: file
      }).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {

          showSuccessMessage("Fichier déposé avec succès");
          // refresh document library webpart
          this.onUploadSuccess();
        }

The events are executed correctly when a file is added.
On my development and internal acceptance environments, it works correctly, and error messages are retrieved from the front by the code:
else {
          let rep: string;
          
          rep = response.statusText;
            
          throw new Error(rep);
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        this.input.value = '';
        showErrorMessage("Votre fichier n'a pas pu être déposé. Nous vous invitons à réessayer dans 2h et nous contacter si le problème persistait.");       

      });

But on the customer's test and production environments, the message is not retrieved, I always get an empty message.
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusDescription = ex.Message; 
What could be causing this difference in response?
I've compared the web.config files and can't find anything.
Parametrisation at the IIS server level?
SharePoint options ?
Thanks for your help
